# Ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}_p(α) $

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, local-field

Is ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}_p(α) $ is $\mathbb{Z}_p[α] $ ?

If $α$ is primitive root of unity, dependentable reference reads that the titled statement holds.
But in general, does the statement hold?

My try: In local fields, rings of integers is the same thing as valuation ring(I don't know hot to prove this). So, there are denominator has no prime factor $p$, so the integer ring is $\mathbb{Z}_p[α] $.

Comment: What if $\alpha=p^{(p+1)/p}$?

Comment: Even easier, note that $\mathbb Q_p(\alpha) = \mathbb Q_p(p^k \alpha)$ for every $k \in \mathbb Z$, but certainly not $\mathbb Z_p[\alpha] = \mathbb Z_p[p^k \alpha]$ in general. (So take $\alpha = p^{-1}\cdot \zeta_n$ for a counterexample. Or maybe most basic, $\alpha= p^{-1}$.)